# Fill NA row with previous value iteratively in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, dataset

Say you have something like this across various weeks in a given df:

```
DoW Value
Mon 1234
Tue NA
Wed 5678
Thu 9123
Fri 4567
Sat 8912
Sun 3456
```

I'd like to fill every Tuesday's NA with Monday's value of it's correspondent week. How can I do this, preferably with the least amount of code possible?

Thanks.

Comment: ``library(zoo); na.locf(DF, na.rm = FALSE)`.  If the leading values cannot be NA then the `na.rm=` argument can be omitted.  If you only want to apply it to one column but not others then `transform(DF, Value = na.locf0(Value))` where `na..locf0` is like `na.locf` but defaults to `na.rm=FALSE` and only handles vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
mydf <- structure(list(DoW = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", 
"Sun"), Value = c(1234L, NA, 5678L, 9123L, 4567L, 8912L, 3456L
)), .Names = c("DoW", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

tuesd_na <- which(mydf$DoW == "Tue" & is.na(mydf$Value))
mydf$Value[tuesd_na] <- mydf$Value[tuesd_na - 1]
mydf
#>   DoW Value
#> 1 Mon  1234
#> 2 Tue  1234
#> 3 Wed  5678
#> 4 Thu  9123
#> 5 Fri  4567
#> 6 Sat  8912
#> 7 Sun  3456
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this with the `tidyr::fill`.

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- tribble(
  ~DoW,  ~Value,
  'Mon', 1234,
  'Tue', NA,
  'Wed', 5678,
  'Thu', 9123,
  'Fri', 4567,
  'Sat', 8912,
  'Sun', 3456
)

fill(df, Value)
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#     DoW Value
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1   Mon  1234
# 2   Tue  1234
# 3   Wed  5678
# 4   Thu  9123
# 5   Fri  4567
# 6   Sat  8912
# 7   Sun  3456
```