# Replace 0 values by using previous value in R

Tags: r, replace

I have some zero values and would like to replace by the previous value in R.

X var      : 1 3 6 0 7 8 0 0 9 8 9 0 0 0 4 7 2 4

X new var  : 1 3 6 6 7 8 8 8 9 8 9 9 9 9 4 7 2 4

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: ok , i got it, replace the elements with 0 by NA, and then i use the na.locf function from the zoo package.

Comment: `dplyr`'s `na_if` and `fill` functions will probably help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dplyr and tidyr packages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(var = c(1,2,3,0,7,8,0,0,9,8,9,0,0,0,4,7,2,4))
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(var = ifelse(var == 0, NA, var)) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(var, .direction = c("down"))
df
```

```
> df
   var
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    7
6    8
7    8
8    8
9    9
10   8
11   9
12   9
13   9
14   9
15   4
16   7
17   2
18   4
```

[Fill NA row with previous value iteratively in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516943/fill-na-row-with-previous-value-iteratively-in-r)

Comment: Oh, Thanks, i really appreciate your answer with all the code.

Comment: @Minh Pham, please, Could you accept my answer?. Look at this. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work